# Substitution problem with $\int e^{-1 \over x}{dx\over x²}$

Tags: integration, substitution

I am trying to comprehend what is happening in this integration problem. I have tried substituting for both $U = {-1 \over x}$ and $U = x²$ but I am not ending up with the correct result on both cases. This is the worked example:

$$\int e^{-1 \over x}{dx\over x²} = \int e^{-1 \over x}d{-1 \over x} = e^{-1 \over x} +C$$

Can anyone help me finding the correct substitution method?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct substitution is $u=-\frac{1}{x}$ given that $du=\frac{1}{x^2}$, so the integral is just $\int e^u du=e^u+C$.

Comment: How is the substitution for $du = {1 \over x²}$ not negative anymore?

Comment: $-\frac{1}{x}=-x^{-1}$. If we take the derivative we get that this equals $(-1)-x^{-1-1}=x^{-2}=\frac{1}{x^2}$.

Answer (score 1):

Substitute $u=-\frac1x,\ du=\frac1{x^2}dx$

$$\int \frac{e^{-1/x}}{x^2}dx=\int e^{-1/x}\cdot\frac{1}{x^2}dx=\int e^u\,du=e^u+C=e^{-1/x}+C$$

Comment: How is the substitution for $du = {1 \over x²}$ not negative anymore?

Comment: @TheAlPaca02 when $f(x)<0$ it doesn't mean that $f'(x)<0$. Something may be less than zero, but increasing. Rewrite $-1/x$ as $-x^{-1}$. Then use the rule $(x^a)'=ax^{a-1}$.

Answer (score 1):

If you do
$$
u=-\frac{1}{x}
$$
you also have
$$
x=-\frac{1}{u},\qquad
dx=\frac{1}{u^2}\,du
$$
so the integral becomes
$$
\int e^u\cdot u^2\cdot\frac{1}{u^2}\,du=\int e^u\,du
$$